# C#, EF 6 - DBContext not opening connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, oracle.manageddataaccess

I'm working with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` (v. 4.122.19.1) and Entity Framework (v. 6.0.0.0).

I created a simple context like this:

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    public FooContext() : base(new OracleConnection(Connection.connection),true)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<FooContext>(null);
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

and test method:

```
[TestMethod]
private static void TestIsConnectionOpen() 
{
    using (var db = new FooContext())
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(ConnectionState.Open, db.Database.Connection.State);
    }
}
```

I expected, that in this case, connection will be automatically open, like in this e.g. https://github.com/entityframeworktutorial/EF6-DBFirst-Demo , but the test fails.

Could someone explain to me why?

`Connection.connection` is a valid connection string, because when I change test method to:

```
[TestMethod]
private static void TestIsConnectionOpen() 
{
    using (var db = new FooContext())
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        Assert.AreEqual(ConnectionState.Open, db.Database.Connection.State);
    }
}
```

then the test passed.

Comment: connection will be opened automatically when an query starts be executing.

Comment: Why do you want the database connection to be opened earlier than needed?

Comment: @3per - thanks, that's the point